# Creating list based on if in excel

Tags: excel

Today, I'm attempting to create a drop down list based on another few tables. To make a long story short, based on what cell C2 (OEM type) says, it will look up in a table and pull a number of items (seal column) based on C2.

I've attached images of everything I'm using. The drop down list would need to be in cell B3. The formula I'm currently using as a source in data validation for the list is as follows:

```
=IF(C2="",SealList,INDEX(SealColumn,MATCH(C2,OEMColumn,0)))
```

SealList is L1:L20
SealColumn is H1:H20
OEMColumn is G1:G20

What am I doing wrong? Any recommendations would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: When I click okay to run it, it says that the formula is producing an error. When I click okay for it to run anyways, it returns nothing.

Comment: What was the error? Did it tell you anything specific?

Comment: No, it didn't unfortunately

Comment: How are you defining `SealList`, `SealColumn`, and `OEMColumn`? It should work if you use the cell ranges (`L1:L20` for example).

Comment: What are you clicking to run it? Is there code behind this somewhere?

Comment: I renamed the cells/cell ranges to those names. To run it, I go into data validation where the formula is located and I hit okay.